# Which to use: react-native-opentok or opentok-react-native

Tags: react-native, opentok

Has anyone used (or contributed to) opentok-react-native and react-native-opentok? Looking for some perspective on which is better maintained or a better choice for a general purpose video conferencing app.

Both seem to have been updated relatively recently (opentok-react-native just this month and react-native-opentok in April). I'm wondering if anyone worked on either and has some backstory on why they both exist and future looking plans for both... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

I'm the author of the [OpenTok React Native library](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react-native) and I continuously update it so developers can use the latest features offered by the OpenTok Mobile SDKs in React Native.

Here are some of the things that this library supports:

- Publishing

  - [Publisher Properties](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react-native/blob/master/docs/OTPublisher.md#properties)
- Subscribing

  - [Subscriber Properties](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react-native/blob/master/docs/OTSubscriber.md#properties)
- Signaling
- Screen sharing
- Events

  - [Session Events](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react-native/blob/master/docs/OTSession.md#events)
  - [Publisher Events](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react-native/blob/master/docs/OTPublisher.md#events)
  - [Subscribing Events](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react-native/blob/master/docs/OTSubscriber.md#events)

You can also find the documentation on how to use the OpenTok React Native API here: https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react-native/tree/master/docs

OpenTok also has a [React](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react) library which has a very similar API so you can use that for your web application.